# 20.04 - Fix Wifi issue network unclaimed (AX201)

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I don't have Wifi on my laptop (Dell, Linux Ubuntu 20.04 no dualboot) since I rebooted it. Before, I had no problem and I did not change anything.
On the reboot, I had a blue screen talking about "MOK Management" and I choose to "Continue boot". Once on the OS, resolution has been changed and I lost Wifi options.
I rebooted it again, resolution has came back to normal but still no Wifi. Oh and I can't connect though Ethernet either.

Here are some infos, sorry for the quality I had to take it myself with my phone : kernel 5.11, Wifi Intel AX201
https://ibb.co/N24wzrt

I saw a lot of answers about it but I can't make it works so if you can help me, it would be great.

EDIT :

Result of `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` :

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

---

EDIT 2 :

Empty result for `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Result for `sudo dkms status` : `backport-iwlwifi, 8324: added`

Result for `modinfo iwlwifi | grep filename` : `modinfo: ERROR: Module iwlwifi not found.`

Comment: Start by disabling Secure Boot in UEFI and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I checked and disabled it already, did not resolve anything

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Done, and thanks for the welcoming :)

Comment: Verrry interesting! May we now see: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `sudo dkms status` and finally: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep filename`

Comment: @chili555 Done ! Hope it will help, because it does not give me any clue as a newbie :D

Comment: Please try: `sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/8613 --all` Reboot and show us again: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep filename`

Comment: @chili555 The remove command show `Error! There are no instances of module: backport-iwlwifi 8613 located in the DKMS tree`. But the autocomplete show me a backport-iwlwifi/8324. Same message after reboot for the `modinfo` command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129483/discussion-between-chili555-and-maxime-picard).

Comment: In our chat, we learned thet the package *linux-modules-extra* that provides the driver iwlwifi, among others, was not installed. We therefore undertook the same fix as the duplicate and all is working as expected.

Comment: @chili555 Thanks again for your time, you're amazing !

Comment: J’étais heureux de le faire, mon ami!